# How do I prevent sitecore from adding a ~ to an image path?

Tags: sitecore

I have a clean install of Sitecore 6.5, DMS 2.0, and the E-Commerce Module and Sample Site (v1.2). When I have the sample site installed, most of the images appear to be broken. The HTML that is rendered includes img src attributes that contain a path that start with /~/. Example:

```
http://~/media/Images/Ecommerce/Examples/Products/Digital%20SLR/D200.ashx?w=250&as=1
```

Now, I'm assuming this is either because the sample site hasn't been updated in a while to stay current with Sitecore changes, or there is a configuration for media paths that get returned from it. Here's an example of the XSLT rendering used to write the image:

```
<img id="product_shot" class="fix" alt="{sc:fld('alt',.)}" title="{sc:fld('alt',.)}" src="/{sc:GetMediaUrl(.)}?w={$ImageWidth}&amp;as=1" />
```

Does anyone know of a way to prevent the image url from being rendered with a ~ when using XSLT? Did I do something wrong with my initial setup and configuration?

Comment: Normally when I use XSLT I use <sc:Image />  Any reason not to use that here?

Comment: Hm, on second thought, have you set up the Wildcard mappings in IIS?  I have seen that cause problems with the media library items before as well.  Do you have any media file URLS that _do_ work?

Comment: @patrickmjones the xslt templates were developed by sitecore, it's the e-commerce starter site example package. The problem is that the src attributes files end up starting with src="//~/" which isn't right. It should only be a single "/". My thought is it's a sitecore configuration thing to prevent sc:GetMediaUrl(.) from returning a value that begins with "/" but I'm not sure where that would be set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John West gives a great breakdown here: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/12/Sitecore-Idiosyncrasies-Media-URLs.aspx

The important info being a configuration of "Media.MediaLinkPrefix".  You can create a patch file, or modify your Web.config to change it to something else.  The places I've read have people changing it to a single dash "-/media"

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Media.RequestExtension">
        <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix">
        <patch:attribute name="value">-/media</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
    <customHandlers>
      <handler trigger="-/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx"/>
    </customHandlers>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I don't think this solves the problem. Even with these changes, the URL gets written out to the img tag ends up starting with src="//-/media/Images/Ecommerc..." and which equates to trying to lookup the hostname "-" (instead of sitecore.local which I have it setup under). So I would either need to remove all the leading "/"'s in the XSLT's, which I am assuming is not the right solution, or is there a way to make sc:GetMediaUrl(.) not begin its return value with a "/" character?

Comment: I can confirm that removing the first "/" renders the correct src="" attribute and the image displays fine, so I'm fairly confident there should be a configuration change here to prevent sc:GetMediaUrl(.) from returning with a beginning "/" character. I would hope Sitecore would ship their example site with a bunch of broken XSLT's

Comment: What you have set under <linkManager> in web.config (or patch override)? Is alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"? What is the hostName attribute in the <sites> section for "website" (or whatever the site is)

Comment: yes, alwaysIncludeServerUrl is at its default value ("false") and the sites entry for the example e-com site doesn't contain a hostName attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which I can think of is to change your web.config like this:

```
InvalidItemNameChars: Add “~“
```

But this will work not only for images but for any content items out there in your Sitecore content tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution. Since I'm setting this up for demo purposes, it'll do just fine.

In web.config, I changed the value of `Media.MediaLinkPrefix` to include the hostname **and** media prefix. Since the Sitecore E-Commerce Example Site XSLT renderings start all calls to `sc:GetMediaUrl(.)` with a `/` character and `sc:GetMediaUrl(.)` itself returns its first character as a `/`, this causes the src attribute value to be written with the full host name and then correctly resolves:

`<img src="//sitecore.local/~/media/Images/Ecommerce/Examples/Products/Digital%20SLR/D200.jpg` />

Far from ideal, but for these purposes, this workaround did the trick.

Comment: Ahhh, I see where the problem is now. Did you try removing the trailing / from the src attribute in the xslt? This may be something that has made it over from a legacy implementation. I appreciate you don't want to do this everywhere... but the above may lead you to other unforseen problems down the road...

Comment: Yes I did, and that worked. I guess I could just go through and start removing those.